# Using MySQL in VC++

Tags: mysql, visual-c++

I am trying to connect to MySQL using C++. The IDE that I am using is Visual C++ 2010. I followed the steps on the MySQL dev page (http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html). I followed the steps exactly as given although i used a different OS(Windows). I get many linker errors in the process, which I am finding difficult to debug. Could somebody direct me towards a better or a simpler approach to acces MySQL using C++.

P.S. I have downloaded mysqlconnector for C++.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [mysql++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/), but you'll encounter the same linker errors I bet.

Have you set the include path (C:...\MySQL Server 5.1\include) and the library path (C:...\MySQL Server 5.1\lib\debug) ? In VC2010 to set global settings you have to :

> VS2010 introduces the user settings
>   file
>   (Microsoft.cpp..users.props)
>   to control global settings including
>   Global search path. These files are
>   located at
>   $(USERPROFILE)\appdata\local\microsoft\msbuild\v4.0
>   directory.
>
> The issue you are seeing is a bug in
>   the UI. To make it possible to change
>   the ordering of these read-only
>   directories, here is the workaround
>   that you can apply:
>
> 1. open up the property manager,
> 2. right click on the .user.props file to bring up the property page
> 3. open up VC++ Directories -> Include Directories, add new paths after
>      $(IncludePath)
> 4. Click on the "Edit" dropdown on VC++ Directories -> Include
>      Directories property, the user
>      directories as well as the inherited
>      values will show up in the upper pane
> 5. you can move the directory orders as you wish and save.
>
> http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/550946/vs-2010-how-to-change-vc-directories-inherited-values-read-only

Comment: MySQL++ has only one known problem with Visual C++ 2010, that being that you can't currently build it as a 64-bit library, so it can't be linked to a 64-bit program.  (That used to work with VC++ 2005 and 2008, and we don't yet know why 2010 breaks it.)  32-bit libraries are the default on Windows, so as long as you follow the instructions and don't change any build settings, you should be fine.

Comment: Warren, in building MySQL++ with VC2010 have you encountered the warning MSB8012 (http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/523864/how-to-fix-msb8012-lib-outputfile).

Comment: I set the include path and all the required configurations fo the linker in the project settings correctly. But the linker errors persist. Tried using Turbo C++ but came to know that mysql connector doesnt work with that. Will try mysql++ for now...